# Vaadin gradle Project HTTP 404 on styles.css

Tags: gradle, vaadin, vaadin7

I've started a new gradle WebProject using vaadin.

here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'    
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

repositories{   
    mavenCentral()  
}  

dependencies{  
    compile group:'com.vaadin', name:'vaadin-server', version:'7.2.3'
    compile group:'com.vaadin', name:'vaadin-client-compiled', version:'7.2.3'
    compile group:'javax.servlet', name:'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
    compile group:'com.google.guava', name:'guava', version:'17.0'
    compile group:'org.mindrot', name:'jbcrypt', version:'0.3m'
    compile group:'org.reflections', name:'reflections', version:'0.9.9-RC1'
}
```

It works fine. Until I run it with "gradle jettyRunWar" it compiles and runs but in the browser the styles.css is missing (HTTP 404)

Part of the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>ch.boxi.jLogin.ui.NavigatorUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: also consider using https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `dependencies` section in your `build.gradle`, you have a dependency to `vaadin-themes` missing. Add the following to your dependencies:

```
compile group:'com.vaadin', name:'vaadin-themes', version:'7.2.3'
```

`vaadin-themes` contains the built-int themes of Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compile the styles.css if you run vaadin in production mode. to disable the production mode you can modify your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
  <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```